# Is there a way to check if a database table already contains a record with a certain value in Yii2

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a basic Yii2 application in which the user can create meals with a status (enum open or closed).
The idea is that there should be only 1 record with the status open.
Is there a simple way in Yii2 to check if there is already a record with open status before adding the new record ?

**Edit**

Apologies for the unclear description of my problem.
What i'am trying to accomplish would look like this:
[image]

So when a new meal is made, the status either has to be closed, or the status of the entry with open has to be edited to be closed so that the new meal can be created with an open status

Comment: show us what have you done / try. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
 // add this custom validator to your model's rules
 ['status', function ($attribute, $params) {
    if ($this->getIsNewRecord() && $this->$attribute === 'open' && Meal::find([$attribute => 'open'])->count()>0)
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Error message.');
 }],
```

Comment: This simple solution is so close!
If i only use the unique validator it doesnt allow me to create more than 2 entries (1 with status open and 1 with status close)
However with targetAttribute it does allow me to make multiple "open" and "closed" entries as the id increments [as you can see here](https://i.imgur.com/nZBvtvJ.png)

Comment: I am sorry, I'm probably not clear with what it is I am trying to do.
The edited answer makes it impossible to make more than 2 entries.
Once there is 1 with the open status and 1 with the closed status it becomes impossible to add more entries.

What i would like is that there can only be 1 entry with "open" and all the others HAVE to be closed, unless the entry with open gets an update and is closed

Answer (score 1):

As you only want one 'open' status record, why do you just make your logic simple.
Before you insert a new record, update all other records status to 'closed', then save the new record.

You better forbide the 'update' action, then if you want an 'open' status record, just create one.

You even can forget the 'status', just use the lastest record as 'open' status record.